# Legend labeling with QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend

I am trying to build an atlas with the QGIS-atlas-function and I want to know if it is possible to label the legend entries (165) with my own entries from the attribut-tabel. Important is that the Legend use the the original symbology colors/patterns from the svg in combination with my own created entries from the attribut-tabel. Is it the right way to try to change the labels in the rulebased layerdesing? And is there an option to do this automatically or do I have to change them manualy?

Here some Screenshots:

[image: Rulebased Layerdesign]

[image: Rules]

Comment: Have you tried printing an example map and then checked the legend?

Comment: If all your rules in the rules-based rendering correspond to different values of the same field you would probably be better off using a Categorized renderer. By using the field that contains the legend entry names for the Categorized renderer, you should end up with the desired result without manually adjusting the legend entry names.